# How to make game custom icon

Tags: game-engine, customization

If I have a game in blender converted into an application,how can I change the icon of an application?

Comment: The same way you change the icon of any application in whatever operating system you are using.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about system application icons, not Blender.

Comment: i have use resource hacker,but it does not work

Comment: Try to change blenderplayer.exe icon on Blender directory with Resource Hacker, then release your game. Changing icon after releasing the game (that is, blend file already embedded in blenderplayer.exe) might break the executable.